# Relationship between the square of the Frobenius norm and the Frobenius norm of the square

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

I am looking to understand the following relationship:

I have a matrix $A$, whose entries are all bounded by $0 \leq a_{i,j} \leq 1$, and follows the constraint $\|A\|_2 = 1$.

Is there  anything that can be said for the relationship between
$\|A\|_F^2$ and $\|A^TA\|_F \sqrt{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \cdots, \sigma_m$ denote all non-zero singular values of $A$, the identity below holds:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \sigma_i^2 = \|A\|_F^2
$$

Also note that $\sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2, \cdots, \sigma_m^2$ are all non-zero singular values of $A^TA$, thus
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \sigma_i^4 = \|A^TA\|_F^2
$$

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$
(\sum_{i=1}^m\sigma_i^2)^2 \leq (\sum_{i=1}^m\sigma_i^4) \cdot m
$$
implying
$$
\|A\|_F^4 \leq m \cdot \|A^TA\|_F^2 \Leftrightarrow\|A\|_F^2\leq \sqrt{m}\|A^TA\|_F
$$

---

**NOTE**: I assume the $N$ in your question is the rank of $A$ here, which of course is smaller than the # of rows and the # of columns of $A$. Thus $N=m$.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Quick (probably obvious) follow up. It doesn't look like you needed to use any of the constraints I put on A, correct? So this would hold for arbitrary matrices?

Comment: Yes. The matrix $A$ is arbitrary.